# global-linum-mode not found

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to install a package that uses `global-linum-mode` and keep getting:

```
  error "Autoloading failed to define function global-linum-mode
```

I was using Emacs 23 and now upgraded to Emacs 24.1 on OSX, using this package:

http://emacsformacosx.com/

However doing a `(require 'linum)` works but a subsequent `(global-linum-mode 1)` gives the same error.

To me it says that global-linum isn't there but from what I've read it's supposed to be there from Emacs 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine.

*Possibly* there's another autoload declaration somewhere in your config which is clobbering the default one?

Or maybe you have another "linum.el" in your load-path? That would be a bad idea.

Does the same thing happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: There was no linum.el in my directory, but there was a linum.elc there (so once upon a time . . ).  Removing that worked! Thanks!